# mkfs - The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I used `fdisk /dev/sda` to create an sda6 partition. Now I want to format it using the `mkfs.ext4` command. I am using CentOS 6.5 Linux distro. But when I run this command I get following error

```
mkfs.ext4 
Could not stat /dev/sda6 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

I am new to Linux and will appreciate any and all help. I have tried this with and without "sudo" and in both cases I get the same result.

```
[root@server1 ~]# sudo fdisk /dev/sda

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): n
First cylinder (1530-3264, default 1530): 2042
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (2042-3264, default 3264): +50MB

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00002158

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         511     4096000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             511        1020     4096000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3            1020        1530     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4            1530        3264    13925376    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1531        2041     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2042        2048       56227+  83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.

[root@server1 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6

mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Could not stat /dev/sda6 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

After restart - >

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00002158

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         511     4096000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             511        1020     4096000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3            1020        1530     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4            1530        3264    13925376    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1531        2041     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2042        2048       56227+  83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.

[root@server1 ~]# partx /dev/sda

## 1:      2048-  8194047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)

## 2:   8194048- 16386047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)

## 3:  16386048- 24578047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)

## 4:  24578048- 52428799 ( 27850752 sectors,  14259 MB)

## 5:  24582144- 32774143 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)

## 6:  32788665- 32901119 (   112455 sectors,     57 MB)

[root@server1 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6

mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)

/dev/sda6 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

[root@server1 ~]#

**IMPORTANT**
i noticed that fdisk /dev/sda - n - 6 - w, partx, mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6 worked on red hat 6.5 rhel i have but is not working for CentOS 6.5. i don't know why.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, after i reboot i get /dev/sda6 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a file system here.

Comment: Also, i am preparing for RHCSA in which i won't have the opportunity for restart. So i am looking to do it without restarting the system.

Comment: Please display what happens after you do a reboot.

Comment: Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00002158

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         511     4096000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             511        1020     4096000   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3            1020        1530     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4            1530        3264    13925376    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1531        2041     4096000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2042        2048       56227+  83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at

Comment: the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
[root@server1 ~]# partx /dev/sda
# 1:      2048-  8194047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)
# 2:   8194048- 16386047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)
# 3:  16386048- 24578047 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)
# 4:  24578048- 52428799 ( 27850752 sectors,  14259 MB)
# 5:  24582144- 32774143 (  8192000 sectors,   4194 MB)
# 6:  32788665- 32901119 (   112455 sectors,     57 MB)
[root@server1 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sda6 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

Comment: [root@server1 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sda6 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

Comment: i hope this helps clarify what i am seeing. Thanks G-man and mdpc for taking interest.

Answer (score 7):

The kernal does not see the changes as you are partitioning your boot drive...

This is because you could have removed the partition that contains your kernel.

You need to reboot or run partprobe.

Comment: Yes, after i reboot i get /dev/sda6 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a file system here. Also, i am preparing for RHCSA in which i won't have the opportunity for restart. So i am looking to do it without restarting the system.

Comment: `partprobe` was all that was needed for me